# how can I find the following problem using laplace transform?

Tags: calculus, computational-mathematics

For example here is the problem: $(t^2 \cos{\omega t})u(t)$

I have to find it using laplace transform; here is what I think it is,

I have  $t^2$$(\cos{\omega t})u(t)$ which I think I can solve them separate and them put the result together such as:

laplace transform of $t^n = n!/s^\left(n+1\right)$ so $t^2 = 2!/s^\left(2+1\right)$ right?

Now laplace transform for $(\cos\omega t)u(t) = s/s^2+\omega^2$  them

$(\cos{\omega t})u(t)= s/s^2+w^2$ so now I think I can put all these together to come up with the answer?? any help please

Comment: why do i get -2? is it any problem?

Comment: You need to be precise of what you are asking here.  Please revise the details and make the title more informative instead of subjective.

Comment: NasuSama, better? thanks for the advise.

Comment: @carlos - the question is still completely unintelligible. In general, you don't "solve" functions, you solve equations. Do you mean you want to find the Laplace transform of a multiplication of functions?

Comment: let me edit it again, thanks

Comment: @carlos - again, "solve" is reserved for equations. you want to "find" the laplace transform of $XX$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

You might want to use this property of the Laplace transform:

$$\large\mathcal{L}(t^nf(t))=(-1)^n\dfrac{d^n\mathcal{L}(f(t))}{ds^n}$$

Where, in your case, you have:

$$\cases{n=2 \\ f(t)=\cos(\omega t)\cdot u(t)}$$

Using this, can you come up with the result ?

**Note:** And by the way, regarding the method you tried to use:

$$\large\mathcal{L}\left(f(t)\cdot g(t)\right)\neq\mathcal{L}\left(f(t)\right)\cdot\mathcal{L}\left(g(t)\right)$$

Comment: I have to ask what is dp?

Comment: Oh well I didn't see you were using $s$ for the variable in Laplace space. This $p$ is simply what you call $s$. I've edited my post.

Comment: are you sure (-1) is to the power of n?

Comment: Yes pretty sure.